# mysql:how to get max id from duplicated row group by 2 columns?

Tags: mysql

I have one table name "sections_content" that has the following columns

[image]

and I want to get max id for each statecode and policyname

So ,for example,the result of statecode CN / IL /IE should be

[image]

How should I write the code for mysql ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this with a `JOIN` on the `MAX` for that group:

```
SELECT * FROM sections_content as t
JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) as id
        FROM sections_content AS tbl
        GROUP BY
            tbl.policyName,
            tbl.statecode
    ) AS maxId
    ON maxId.id=t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** keywords to get the maximum number.

Exp: Having tables; **table1** and **table2** as in your database. check below queries.

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.statecode, table2.policyname, sections_content.student_lga_of_origin 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.policyname = table2.policyname
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 1
```